# How to handle more Files Handling in Java 8 in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallelstream

In my java web application is a file based integration.  They used to send the bunch of xml files (example: 10000) in our production server opt/app/proceed/ folder.  But as per the current configuration our application able to handle 200 files in a sequential processing. Due to this, delay in the processing of files.  I am trying to increase the number of files processing in parallel way. Please find the block of code for your reference.

```java
public class FileEx {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       String fileDir = "C:\\Users\\inputfiles"; //contains more than 10000 files
       new FileEx().traverseFilesFromDir(new File(fileDir));
   }

   public void traverseFilesFromDir(File dir) throws IOException {
       List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
       if (dir == null || !dir.isDirectory()) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid directory (value: " + dir + ").");
       }
       File[] acknFiles = dir.listFiles();
       int fileCount = (acknFiles == null ? 0 : acknFiles.length);

       System.out.println("fileCount:::::::::" + fileCount);

       Arrays.sort(acknFiles, new Comparator<File>() {
           public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
               return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
           }
       });

       **int maxNoFiles = acknFiles.length <= 500 ? acknFiles.length : 500;**
       System.out.println(acknFiles.length + " Ackn found and starting to process oldest " + maxNoFiles + " files.");

       for (int i = 0; i < maxNoFiles; i++) {
           files.add(acknFiles[i]);
       }

       int fileCount1 = (files == null ? 0 : files.size());

       if (fileCount1 > 0) {
           for (int i = 0; i < fileCount1; i++) {

               boolean success = true;// processFile(files.get(i));
               if (success) {
                   System.out.println("File Successfully processed.");
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

How to proceed to change the way of file processing.  Awaiting support/guidance needed.

Comment: Please describe what you already tried and what problems you are facing. There are a lot of good tutorials about asynchronous Java processing e.g. from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-asynchronous-programming) that can help you more than any answer here.

Comment: Which kind of processi is done by processFile(files.get(i));?  It is not always true that parallel processing increase speed. It is also not clear if the bottleneck id the Filesystem access or the processing, or both

Answer (score 0):

// java 8.1 onwards Paraller stream you can use
// here paralell() by default is executed using ForkJoinPool.commonPool()

```
Files.lines(Paths.get( files.get(i))
  .parallel()
  .map(Your_FileBean::new) 
  .forEach(/*process Your_FileBean*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via [`Files.walk()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-), which returns a `Stream<Path>` object. If you want to process this stream in parallel you can experiment with `parallel()` or `collect(Collectors.toList()).parallelStream()`. Because `Files.walk()` evaluates lazily, `parallel()` alone may not make efficient use of all available cores.

Onto that you can apply [sorting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) and [filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) as needed. Your processing step could be realised through a [`forEachOrdered()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-) at the end of the stream.

Here's an example:

```java
Files.walk(Paths.get("/path/to/root/directory")) // create a stream of paths
    .collect(Collectors.toList()) // collect paths into list to better parallize
    .parallelStream() // process this stream in multiple threads
    .filter(Files::isRegularFile) // filter out any non-files (such as directories)
    .map(Path::toFile) // convert Path to File object
    .sorted((a, b) -> Long.compare(a.lastModified(), b.lastModified())) // sort files date
    .limit(500) // limit processing to 500 files (optional)
    .forEachOrdered(f -> {
        // do processing here
        System.out.println(f);
    });
```